# How to generate random path lengths in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path

I want to generate an array of 200 paths with varying (random) lengths.....

[image]

I can *easily* generate the 200 paths.

I'm struggling to find a method or tool to **randomize the path lengths**. I could, of course, do the randomization manually, but there surely must be a more automated method.

I am aware that the **Astute Graphics Extend Path tool** will do this...
 but I **do *not*** have that tool available due to version requirements.

I've scoured the internet to try and find a script, since it seems like such a simple matter. I can't find anything. I may need to try writing a script. I *have* started researching this, but it's beginning to look like writing something as simple as `PathItem.length = rand()` may take longer to actually learn how to write properly.

##### Is anyone aware of any method which will randomize path lengths in Illustrator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Easiest way....

- Create the path array and make sure it is **not** grouped.
- Select all and choose `Object > Transform > Transform Each...`
- Decrease the `Horizontal Scale` percentage
- Make sure the 9-point origin is set to left center
- Tick the `Random` box....

[image]

Path lengths will be between whatever you use for the Horizontal Scale and 100%.

You can repeatedly tick and untick the `Random` box to get different results each time, until you are happy. Then just click `OK`.

---

##### Another method....

This method can be helpful is you need more control over the path lengths. While I use a random path here, the vertical path can be any configuration - a curve, specific insets, etc. Allowing you to "shape" the lengths more.

Draw a vertical path across the horizontal path array..

[image]

Choose `Effect > Distort & Transform > Roughen...` And play with the settings to get a very random path.

[image]

Click `OK` and then choose `Object > Expand Appearance` to "bake in" the randomization on the path (making it a standard path).

- **Select All** and grab the **Shape Builder Tool**.
- Hold down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key and click-drag across one side of the random path.

This will remove all the stroke parts on *that* side of the random path.

Then select and delete the random path....

[image]

This will leave you an array of random length paths...

[image]

---

Of note: One *may* think that Pathfinder > Divide would be helpful here as opposed to Shape Builder. It is *not*. The Divide operation seemingly *joins* the random path segments to the horizontal array segments, **connecting them**. Meaning one would need to then *manually* go in and delete each and every connecting segment.

Comment: Nice work around. Yeah, either this or custom scripting.

Comment: @Lucian cant you use transform tool with randomized length then distribute that?

Comment: @joojaa Transform tool? I assume you mean effect.. and F***** me! The path array must've been grouped when I tried it before.. updating answer....

Comment: I hate when I miss something so simple as ungrouping first... I honestly couldn't figure out *why* the transform functions weren't working as I expected them to. Perhaps 4am isn't an optimal time to be working `:)`.

Comment: wow, I didn't even know about those options in the transform panel :))) Why are you working at 4am @Scott ?

Comment: @Scott Io, Saturnalia. Merry X-mas . ‍️